# Heroku can't find files in my Ruby on Rails app - even though they are right there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

When I try to access my site, then check my Heroku logs, I see this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'reset'
>   2012-06-13T02:31:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in
>   /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:4)):

(application.css contains the line  *= require reset)

Then I thought to run "heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all" but this gives a similar error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       couldn't find file 'main/first.js.coffee'
       (in /tmp/build_3428u21sggsoc/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:1)
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
```

(That file is the first one required from my application.js, which has first line "//= require main/first.js.coffee")

In summary: my application runs fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, the files can no longer be found. Any ideas why?

Edit: here is the project tree.  (There is one more directory before the app one, and that is the main project directory that also contains config, db, log, etc)

Another edit: there is no problem with .gitignore, or .slugignore.

[image: project tree showing first.js.coffee]

[image: application.js]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your project file tree?

Comment: All of your files are checked into git? And you are running on the cedar stack?

Comment: Yes, they are all checked into git and I am on Cedar.

Comment: why is it looking in `/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`? Note that app directory is repeated, is this the norm for heroku?

Comment: I don't know, that is a good question.  I figured Heroku just named the base file "app" generically.  I named it something specific to my project.

Comment: 1) if you just put require_tree . in application.js does that change things on heroku?  2) is jquery being included correctly?  want to be sure the asset pipeline is working at all on the heroku side

Comment: Another note, remember the asset pipeline will compress js/css assets FOR YOU, so no need to include the min version of jquery, since that just makes debugging harder. Also, shouldn't you be requiring jquery before any of your own project js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I would suggest you to run your application in production mode on your local computer. There are some errors (in assets but I also found some in routing) which can have impact only for production environment so you can test and fix them locally instead of having to do it from the production server.

About the asset precompilation on Heroku, the solution given by akjoe should result in compiled assets tracked in git repo : with this option, you should disable the asset precompilation which happen on Heroku and let Rails serve you assets (set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your `production.rb` file) but this is not the best way to deal with the asset pipeline as you lost one of his major benefice which is freeing your rails application of request for asset.
To make it working properly, you should setup something like heroku explain : [Using Rack::Cache with Memcached for Static Asset Caching in Rails 3.1+](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31)

I would also suggest you to try the assets precompilation locally in production environment `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. To see if you got any error.

Finally you may want to check this different links to find useful information :

- [Rails 3.1+ Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar)
- [Railscasts : #279 Understanding the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)
- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've had almost exactly the same problem and similar errors with stylesheets edits not taking effect... I found that I would edit css (or as in your case references to css files) which seemed to be ignored by Heroku. Turns out Heroku was ONLY referencing the stylesheets in the `public/assets` directory. I cleared this directory and was able to get it working. 
I later found that you need to precompile your assets directory BEFORE you checkin to git. You would do this as follows:

1. Precompile assets directory: `rake assets:precompile`
2. Add the project files to the current Git repository: `git add .`
3. Checkin the file changes to the current Git repository: `git commit
   -am "description goes here"`
4. Push the files to Heroku: `git push heroku master` (substitute
   'master' for the branch you wish to push to Heroku).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I followed your instructions but am still getting the same error when deploying to Heroku: couldn't find file 'main/first.js.coffee'