# Heroku asset pipeline isn't finding handlebars.runtime.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, handlebars.js

In the manifest file, we have

```
//= require handlebars.runtime
```

In development it works fine, but on heroku we are getting an error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'handlebars.runtime'

  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:11)):
    1: = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    2: = javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}" if js_file_exists?("#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}")
    3:     
    4: -#  Append your own using content_for :javascripts
  app/views/layouts/_javascripts.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_layouts__javascripts_html_haml__1848877102237238272_50436400'
  app/views/layouts/landing.html.haml:35:in `block in _app_views_layouts_landing_html_haml__157312279246923607_45507260'
  app/views/layouts/landing.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_landing_html_haml__157312279246923607_45507260'
```

We aren't precompiling and we dont get any errors on the compile on heroku.
Any ideas on how to get this working properly?

Comment: I believe you solved it already. However, for others who came across this thread, check out: [Heroku can't find files in my Ruby on Rails app - even though they are right there?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11088726/615434)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rails isn't adding `.js` to the end of the file name. Try adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the ember variant in your environment files (i.e. development.rb, production.rb). If you don't configure this, the version of Ember used defaults to development when the Rails environment is development, and similarly for production.

Source: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails